# How Gaussian curvature is affected by a conformal map (using forms)

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

This is an exercise from Tu's book *Differential Geometry.* Let us say we have a two Riemannian manifolds $M$ and $M'$ of dimension 2 with a diffeomorphism $T:M\to M'$ between them. Say $T$ is conformal, i.e., for every point $p\in M$, there is a positive number $a(p)$ such that $$\langle T_*(u),T_*(v)\rangle_{M',F(p)} = a(p)\langle u,v\rangle_{M,p}$$ for all $u,v\in T_pM$. We must determine the relationship between the Gaussian curvatures between the two manifolds.

In this section of the book Tu gives a version of Theorem Egregium in terms of forms, where for an orthonormal frame $e_1,e_2$ we have the Gaussian curvature is given by
$$K = \Omega^1_2(e_1,e_2)$$ where $\Omega^1_2$ is a curvature form. We also have that the Gaussian curvature at a point is given by $$K_p = \langle R_p(u,v)v,u\rangle$$ for any orthonormal basis $u,v$ for $T_pM$. Further, we know that $$\langle R(e_1,e_2)e_2, e_1\rangle = \Omega^1_2(e_1,e_2).$$

At the moment it is fairly unclear to me how to work with these notions of curvature and the conformal map property to get a relationship. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just a heads up (not enough characters to submit an edit request) - you've missed out the $a(p)$ on the RHS of your first equation.

Comment: Good catch! I fixed it now.

Comment: _Hint_: If you had a formula (or a process) that relates the curvature to the metric, and in addition if you took into account, that essentially, you have two metrics, the original one and the same one, but multiplied by function $a$, you would be able to calculate the curvatures in both cases. Do you have any formula for $R$ in terms of the metric?

Comment: Are you referring to the formula relating $R$ to the connection? That is, $R(X,Y)s = \nabla_X\nabla_Ys - \nabla_Y\nabla_Xs - \nabla_{[X,Y]}s$? And maybe also the Koszul formula?

Comment: You are on the right track. I am not too sure at the moment how to make this calculations in terms of the curvature form, albeit it should be possible. I posted an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98634/2002) with calculations using the Koszul formula. See if this helps.

Comment: Ok I will see what I can figure out using the Koszul formula. If you think of any hints as to how to use the curvature form, I would be interested to know because as of now I have little idea how to use it.

Comment: By the way, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2890074/2002) is the exact same question. I don't think that you question is a duplicate, because the old one is still not answered.

Comment: @luthien: For some reason this question just came back to the front page. I answered it many months ago. Do you have questions about my answer? If not, please accept it and let's be done with this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sketch of how the computation should go. By pulling back the metric from $M'$ to $M$, we may just consider one manifold $M$ with two Riemannian metrics, one a positive scalar multiple $a$ of the other. Let's write $\lambda = \sqrt a$.

You get orthonormal coframes for the two metrics, $\theta^1,\theta^2$ and $\tilde\theta^1,\tilde\theta^2$, related by $\tilde\theta^i = \lambda\theta^i$, $i=1,2$. Now differentiate and work out the structure equations to determine that (perhaps depending on your sign convention) the connection form
$$\tilde\omega_2^1 = \omega_2^1 + \left(-\frac{\lambda_2}\lambda\theta^1 + \frac{\lambda_1}\lambda\theta^2\right),$$
where $d\lambda = \lambda_1\theta^1+\lambda_2\theta^2$. This should lead to
$$\tilde\Omega_2^1 = \Omega_2^1 + \left(\Big(\frac{\lambda_1}\lambda\Big)_1 + \Big(\frac{\lambda_2}\lambda\Big)_2\right) \theta^1\wedge\theta^2.$$

(The multiplying factor is often written as $\lambda = e^\rho$, and then you are ending up, of course, with the Laplacian of $\rho$ as the additive factor in the curvature.)

**EDIT**: Time has passed. It seems obvious to me now that I dropped a term. There should be the additional term $\pm d\log\lambda\wedge\omega_2^1$ in the expression for $\tilde\Omega_2^1$.

Comment: Hello, I was just wondering what those subscripts underneath the fractions in the final expression signify. I tried computing the differential of $\bar{\omega}^1_2$ and I found a slightly different expression involving squares: $\bar{\Omega}^1_2=\Omega^1_2-\frac{(\lambda_1)^2+(\lambda_2)^2}{a}\theta_1\wedge\theta_2$.

Comment: I explained that four lines from the bottom. They represent derivatives (slightly different from partial derivatives, since the coframe is orthonormal). Curvature will always involve second derivatives!

Comment: @QuaereVerum You made me look at this again and I realized I'd been sloppy the first time a long time ago. Please see the edit.

Comment: @Quaere I'm writing $d(\lambda_1/\lambda) = (\lambda_1/\lambda)_1\theta^1 + (\lambda_1/\lambda)_2\theta^2$, but there also are terms from differentiating $\theta^1$ and $\theta^2$, which apparently I overlooked. I don't understand what you're doing. $\lambda_1$ is a function, as well.

Comment: Oh, of course, I overlooked that, treating it as a constant. That explains a lot. I will delete some of my past comments now that this is clear, to avoid clutter. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @TedShifrin really useful. Does $\pm$ depend again on convention? 
By structural equations $0=d\theta^1+\omega^1_2\wedge\theta^2$ and $0=d\theta^2-\omega^1_2\wedge\theta^1$, I got the term as $((\lambda_2/\lambda)\omega^1_2\wedge\theta^2+(\lambda_1/\lambda)\omega^1_2)\wedge\theta^1) = - d log\lambda \wedge \omega^1_2$. Does such term play a role in the computation of the Gaussian curvature $\overline\Omega^1_2(\overline e_1, \overline e_2)$? For $n=2$ it seems no according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Scalar_curvature_2). thanks!

Comment: @l4teLearner Yes, the sign issue permeates differential geometry, depending on whether we work with the frame bundle with a left or right action. The wikipedia formula has plenty of correction terms; I haven’t worked it out, but I bet the last term is precisely the $d\log\lambda\wedge \omega_2^1$ term.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again but I would have other two questions: 1) what is meant by left or right action on the frame bundle? I have found instead $\tilde\Omega_2^1 = \Omega_2^1 - \left(\Big(\frac{\lambda_1}\lambda\Big)_1 + \Big(\frac{\lambda_2}\lambda\Big)_2\right) \theta^1\wedge\theta^2$ and I wonder if this is for the same reason. It matches wiki curvature formula and gives -1 for the [Poincarè half plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model#Metric) when plugging an orthonormal frame. 
2) Why does the dlog term vanish for n=2 in the curvature formula?

Comment: Does the rotation group act on the right on (co)frames or on the left? Look at standard geometry texts. Does $\Omega_2^1 = +K\theta^1\wedge\theta^2$ or $-K$?  ... With regard to your upper half-plane example, it's excellent. In this case, in fact, $\lambda_2/\lambda = -1$, and so the term $(\lambda_2/\lambda)_2 = 0$. To get the curvature, you actually need the $d\log\lambda\wedge \omega_2^1$ term. This gives you $-(\lambda_2/\lambda)\theta^1\wedge\theta^2 = \theta^1\wedge\theta^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I am really confused now. For the half plane, if I am not mistaken, $\lambda = \sqrt{1/{y^2}}=1/y$, no? So I get $\lambda_2 = -1/y^2$ and $(\lambda_2/\lambda) = -1/y$. Maybe I am doing some dumb error somewhere. But checking on other places, I see the formula for the gaussian curvature does not have the log term with n=2, for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606919/gauss-curvature-of-conformal-metrics) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270598/curvature-of-conformally-equivalent-flat-metrics)

Comment: Maybe because in those other examples the "starting" space is flat?

Comment: @l4teLearner This is my final comment here. You are not paying attention to what the symbols mean. We are defining $d\lambda = \sum \lambda_i \theta^i$. These are *not* partial derivatives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145697/discussion-between-l4telearner-and-ted-shifrin).