# Minimal Surface has constant Gaussian Curvature After Conformal Change $\tilde{g}=-Kg$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, conformal-geometry, minimal-surfaces

**Question: suppose $M\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a minimal surface (mean curvature $H \equiv 0$), show that after conformal change  $$\tilde{g}=-Kg$$
 the Gaussian curvature $\tilde{K}\equiv 1$**.

Since $H \equiv 0$ implies $k_1=-k_2$, where $k_1,k_2$ are principal curvature and we assume $k_1\geq k_2$, we get $K=-k_1^2<0$, so $\tilde{g}=-Kg$ is a conformal change indeed.

I try to verify above statement by direct computation via moving frame:

Let $\{\omega^i\},\{\tilde{\omega}^i\}$ be orthogonal coframes, and suppose $g = (\omega^1)^2 + (\omega^2)^2$, and $\tilde{g} = (\tilde{\omega}^1)^2 + (\tilde{\omega}^2)^2$, then $$\tilde{\omega}^i=\sqrt{-K}\omega^i$$ Also, we suppose connection 1-form $\omega_1^2 = p\omega^1+q\omega^2$.

\begin{align*}
d \tilde{\omega}^1 &= d(\sqrt{-K}\omega^1)=-(\sqrt{-K})_2 \omega^1 \wedge \omega^2+\sqrt{-K}d\omega^1\\
&=-(\sqrt{-K})_2 \omega^1 \wedge \omega^2+\sqrt{-K}\omega^2\wedge\omega_2^1\\
&=-(\sqrt{-K})_2 \omega^1 \wedge \omega^2+p\sqrt{-K} \omega^1\wedge \omega^2
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
d \tilde{\omega}^2 &= d(\sqrt{-K}\omega^2)=(\sqrt{-K})_1 \omega^1 \wedge \omega^2+\sqrt{-K}d\omega^2\\
&=(\sqrt{-K})_1 \omega^1 \wedge \omega^2+\sqrt{-K}\omega^1\wedge\omega_1^2\\
&=(\sqrt{-K})_1 \omega^1 \wedge \omega^2+q\sqrt{-K}\omega^1\wedge\omega^2
\end{align*}

where $d(\sqrt{-K})=(\sqrt{-K})_1 \omega^1 + (\sqrt{-K})_2 \omega^2 $.

Then according to structure equation: $d\omega^i=\omega^j\wedge\omega_j^i$ and $d\tilde{\omega}^i=\tilde{\omega}^j\wedge\tilde{\omega}_j^i$, we get
$$
\tilde{\omega}_2^1 = \omega_2^1 + \frac{(\sqrt{-K})_2}{\sqrt{-K}}\omega^1 - \frac{(\sqrt{-K})_1}{\sqrt{-K}}\omega^2 
$$

Take exterior differential

\begin{align*}
d\tilde{\omega}_2^1 &= d \omega_2^1-\left[\left(\frac{(\sqrt{-K})_1}{\sqrt{-K}}\right)_1+ \left(\frac{(\sqrt{-K})_2}{\sqrt{-K}}\right)_2 \right]\omega^1\wedge \omega^2 \quad \quad \quad \quad (1) 
\end{align*}

By Cartan structure equation: 
$$\Omega_2^1 = d \omega_2^1 = R_{1212}\omega^1 \wedge \omega^2 = K\omega^1 \wedge \omega^2 \quad \quad \quad \quad (2) $$
 Similarly, $$\tilde{\Omega}_2^1 = d \tilde{\omega_2^1 }= \tilde{K}\tilde{\omega}^1 \wedge \tilde{\omega}^2 = -K \tilde{K}\omega^1 \wedge \omega^2 \quad \quad \quad \quad (3) $$

Then combine $(1),(2),(3)$:
$$\tilde{K}=-1 + \frac{1}{K}\left[\left(\frac{(\sqrt{-K})_1}{\sqrt{-K}}\right)_1+ \left(\frac{(\sqrt{-K})_2}{\sqrt{-K}}\right)_2 \right]$$

So the problem converts to verify the following PDE of Gaussian curvature $K$ is true:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{K}\left[\left(\frac{(\sqrt{-K})_1}{\sqrt{-K}}\right)_1+ \left(\frac{(\sqrt{-K})_2}{\sqrt{-K}}\right)_2 \right]=2 \quad  \quad  \quad (4)
\end{equation}
Since we haven't really use the fact that $M$ is a minimal surface (except for $K<0$), I guess the above equation follows from $M$ is a minimal surface. But, frankly, I have no idea how to preceed.

So I try to compute a concrete example of minimal surface to get some hints, for example, the helicoid
$$
x(u,v)=(a \sinh(v) \cos(u),a \sinh(v) \sin(u),au)
$$
then my computation shows that $K=-\frac{1}{\cosh^2(v)}$, plug into $\frac{1}{K}\left[\left(\frac{(\sqrt{-K})_1}{\sqrt{-K}}\right)_1+ \left(\frac{(\sqrt{-K})_2}{\sqrt{-K}}\right)_2 \right] = 1$ instead of $2$, so I got puzzled. Is my computation for $\tilde{K}$ having something wrong or the question itself having something wrong. Could you please help me with that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your computation is wrong, I believe. Check the last lines of $d\tilde\omega^j$. Also, I really do *not* like your notation of dividing $2$-forms, even though it is not nonsensical. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126835/how-gaussian-curvature-is-affected-by-a-conformal-map-using-forms/3129169#3129169) might be helpful.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your comment! I will check my computation and try to rephrase my notation.

Comment: @TedShifrin Dear Ted, your post is really helpful and now I think I get my correct $\tilde{K}$. But still, I cannot preceed to verify (4). Could you please help me look at that part? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$

Yes, you're correct that we need to make use of the fact that we're starting with a minimal surface. So we will work with the full moving frames arsenal. Let $e_1,e_2$ be the principal directions, and let the principal curvatures be $\pm k$ with $k>0$. Then we have 
$$\omega_3^1 = k\omega^1 \quad\text{and}\quad \omega_3^2 = -k\omega^2.$$
When when you make your conformal metric change you have
$$\tilde\omega^1 = k\omega^1 = \omega_3^1 \quad\text{and}\quad \tilde\omega^2 = k\omega^2 = -\omega_3^2.$$
Now the rest just follows from the structure equations.
We have
\begin{CD}\begin{align*}
d\tilde\omega^1 &= \tilde\omega^2\wedge\tilde\omega_2^1  \\
@| & \\
d\omega_3^1 &= \omega_3^2\wedge\omega_2^1 = -\tilde\omega^2\wedge\omega_2^1,
\end{align*}\end{CD}
and similarly for $\tilde\omega^2$. It follows immediately that $\tilde\omega_2^1 = -\omega_2^1$. Thus,
$$\tilde K\tilde\omega^1\wedge\tilde\omega^2 = d\tilde\omega_2^1 = -d\omega_2^1 = -K\omega^1\wedge\omega^2,$$
and since $\tilde\omega^1\wedge\tilde\omega^2 = k^2\omega^1\wedge\omega^2 = -K\omega^1\wedge\omega^2$, we conclude that $\tilde K = 1$, as desired.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't realize I can use $d \omega^i_j = \omega_j^k \wedge \omega_k^i$ (Codazzi equation) and after that everything is quite elegant and simple! Thank you for your answer, Ted.

Comment: One more question: so PDE (4) is true as a corollary? I tried to compute the example of helicoid, after plug into (4), it doesn't hold. So I feel confused. Maybe I should check one more example.

Comment: I think your formula is off for the Gaussian curvature — you should have a fourth power. Also, remember that we have to compute the derivatives with respect to an orthonormal frame, not just with respect to the parametrizing coordinates.