# Gaussian curvature is affected by a conformal map

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying Tu's book Differential Geometry.
Problem is

> Two Riemannian manifolds $M$ and $M′$ of dimension 2 with a diffeomorphism $T:M→M′$ between them. For every point $p \in M$, there is a positive number $a(p)$ such that
> $$⟨T^∗(u),T^∗(v)⟩_{M′,F(p)}=a(p)⟨u,v⟩_{M,p}$$
> for all $u,v\in T_pM$. Find the relationship between the Gaussian curvatures between the two manifolds.

I saw [How Gaussian curvature is affected by a conformal map (using forms)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126835/how-gaussian-curvature-is-affected-by-a-conformal-map-using-forms?noredirect=1&lq=1). But I cannot derive $\tilde\omega_2^1 = \omega_2^1 + \left(-\frac{\lambda_2}\lambda\theta^1 + \frac{\lambda_1}\lambda\theta^2\right)$ part in Ted Shifrin's answer. Can you explain it more specifically? Thank you.

Comment: Did you compute $d\tilde\theta^i$?

Comment: I think that $d\tilde{\theta}^1 = d(\lambda \theta^1)$ ,but $\lambda$ is function of $p$ and $\theta$ is coframe, so $d(\lambda \theta^i) = d(\lambda) \wedge \theta^i - \lambda d(\theta^i)$ and  $d(\lambda ) =  \lambda_1 \theta^1 + \lambda_2 \theta^2$, so  $d\tilde{\theta}^1 =  (\lambda_1 \theta^1 + \lambda_2 \theta^2)\wedge \theta^1 - \lambda d(\theta^1)$.

Comment: IS this formula right? then $d\tilde{\theta}^1 =  -\lambda_2 \theta^1 \wedge \theta^2 - \lambda d(\theta^1)$ is right?

Comment: No minus sign. OK, then go on and fit with the structure equations.

Comment: @TedShifrin, 
$d\tilde{\theta}^1 =  -\lambda_2 \theta^1 \wedge \theta^2 + \lambda d(\theta^1) = -\lambda \tilde{w_2^1}\wedge \theta^2$, and 

$d\tilde{\theta}^2 =  \lambda_1 \theta^1 \wedge \theta^2 + \lambda d(\theta^2) = \lambda \tilde{w_2^1}\wedge \theta^1$

Assume $\tilde{w_2^1} = a \theta^1 + b \theta^2$, then 

$-\lambda_2 \theta^1 \wedge \theta^2 + \lambda d(\theta^1) = - a \lambda \theta^1 \wedge \theta^2$.

But I cannot get $a$ due to $d(\theta^1)$.

Comment: You haven't used the original structure equations, have you?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I think i used first structural equation.