# Gauss curvature of $(M, f^2 g)$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

When I am reading a book about *minimal surface*, there is a question show up.

> Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemann surface, and $f$ be a positive smooth function on $M$, then the curvature of $(M, f^2 g)$ is given by
> $$K_g=\Delta_g\ln f+f^2K_{f^2g}\,.$$

I think it maybe a trivial question that just need to calculate carefully, but I have failed to get the answer. Is there any other way to obtain this result?

Comment: What do you mean by "another way"? What way have you tried?

Comment: If you search, you will find this question several times. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126835/how-gaussian-curvature-is-affected-by-a-conformal-map-using-forms/3129169#3129169) is one solution, using moving frames; I did catch a missing term and edited later.